# How to implement search(edit text) functionality?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a listview that gets all words from sqlite and a edittext (that I want to filter/search words from the database).

I would like to implement a TextWatcher, it's much better, but I don't know how to do it using my code. I'm a newbie.

```
public class DictionaryListActivity extends Activity {

TextView userTextView;
EditText searchEditText;

ListView dictionaryListView;

String logTagString="DICTIONARY";
ArrayList<WordDefinition> allWordDefinitions=new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();


DictionaryDatabaseHelper myDictionaryDatabaseHelper;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary_list);

    Log.d("DICTIONARY", "second activity started");


    userTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.personTextView);
    userTextView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.USER_NAME_STRING)+"'s Dictionary");

    searchEditText=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);

    dictionaryListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.dictionaryListView);

    myDictionaryDatabaseHelper=new DictionaryDatabaseHelper(this, "Dictionary", null, 1);
    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.SHARED_NAME_STRING, MODE_PRIVATE);


    boolean initialized=sharedPreferences.getBoolean("initialized", false);

    if (initialized==false) {
        //Log.d(logTagString, "initializing for the first time");
        initializeDatabase();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("initialized", true);
        editor.commit();

    }else {
        Log.d(logTagString, "db already initialized");
    }

    allWordDefinitions=myDictionaryDatabaseHelper.getAllWords();

    dictionaryListView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup arg2) {
            if (view==null) {
                view=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }
            TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listItemTextView);
            textView.setText(allWordDefinitions.get(position).word);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return allWordDefinitions.size();
        }
    });

    dictionaryListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                long arg3) {
            Intent intent =new Intent(DictionaryListActivity.this, WordDefinitionDetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("word", allWordDefinitions.get(position).word);
            intent.putExtra("definition", allWordDefinitions.get(position).definition);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });



private void initializeDatabase() {
    InputStream inputStream=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dictionary);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    DictionaryLoader.loadData(bufferedReader, myDictionaryDatabaseHelper);

}

 }
```

DictionaryDatabaseHelper

```
public class DictionaryDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

final static String DICTIONARY_DATABASE="dictionary";
final static String ITEM_ID_COLUMN="id";
final static String WORD_COLUMN="word";
final static String DEFINITION_COLUMN="definition";


final static String CREATE_DATABASE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE+" ( "+
ITEM_ID_COLUMN+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
WORD_COLUMN+" TEXT , "+
DEFINITION_COLUMN+" TEXT)";


final static String ON_UPGRADE_QUERY="DROP TABLE "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE;

Context context;


public DictionaryDatabaseHelper(Context context, String name,
        CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DICTIONARY_DATABASE, factory, version);
    this.context=context;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(CREATE_DATABASE_QUERY);    
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    database.execSQL(ON_UPGRADE_QUERY);
    onCreate(database);

}

public long insertData(WordDefinition wordDefinition) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(WORD_COLUMN, wordDefinition.word);
    values.put(DEFINITION_COLUMN, wordDefinition.definition);

    return database.insert(DICTIONARY_DATABASE, null, values);      

}

public long updateData(WordDefinition wordDefinition) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

    values.put(WORD_COLUMN, wordDefinition.word);
    values.put(DEFINITION_COLUMN, wordDefinition.definition);

    return database.update(DICTIONARY_DATABASE, values, WORD_COLUMN+" =?", new String[]{wordDefinition.word});  

}

public void deleteData(WordDefinition wordDefinition) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    String queryString="DELETE FROM "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE+" WHERE "+WORD_COLUMN+" = '"+wordDefinition.word+"'";

    database.execSQL(queryString);
}

public ArrayList<WordDefinition> getAllWords() {
    ArrayList<WordDefinition> arrayList=new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getReadableDatabase();

    String selectAllQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE;
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectAllQueryString, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {            
            WordDefinition wordDefinition=new WordDefinition(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_COLUMN)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DEFINITION_COLUMN)));
            arrayList.add(wordDefinition);              
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());          
    }   
    return arrayList;
}

public WordDefinition getWordDefinition(String word) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getReadableDatabase();
    WordDefinition wordDefinition=null;

    String selectQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE+ " WHERE "+WORD_COLUMN+" = '"+word+ "'";
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectQueryString, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        wordDefinition=new WordDefinition(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_COLUMN)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DEFINITION_COLUMN)));

    }   

    return wordDefinition;

}

public WordDefinition getWordDefinition(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getReadableDatabase();
    WordDefinition wordDefinition=null;

    String selectQueryString="SELECT * FROM "+DICTIONARY_DATABASE+ " WHERE "+ITEM_ID_COLUMN+" = '"+id+ "'";
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery(selectQueryString, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        wordDefinition=new WordDefinition(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(WORD_COLUMN)), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DEFINITION_COLUMN)));

    }   

    return wordDefinition;

}

public void initializeDatabaseFortheFirstTime(ArrayList<WordDefinition> wordDefinitions) {
    SQLiteDatabase database=this.getWritableDatabase();
    database.execSQL("BEGIN");

    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();

    for (WordDefinition wordDefinition : wordDefinitions) {
        contentValues.put(WORD_COLUMN, wordDefinition.word);
        contentValues.put(DEFINITION_COLUMN, wordDefinition.definition);            
        database.insert(DICTIONARY_DATABASE, null, contentValues);
    }
    database.execSQL("COMMIT");

}


}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "implementing TextWatcher" can you explain bit more

Comment: see https://codeshare.io/aFQT7

Answer (score 0):

Try this following code:

Globally you need to defined searchProducts.

```
List<WordDefinition> searchProducts;  

searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
       }

       @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         String text = s.toString();
         getSearchResult(text);
        }
});
```

In method of getSearchResult you can see searching logic. You can change as per your requirements.

```
public void getSearchResult(String s) {
                    myDictionaryDatabaseHelper=new DictionaryDatabaseHelper(this, "Dictionary", null, 1);
                    allWordDefinitions=myDictionaryDatabaseHelper.getAllWords();
                    searchProducts = new ArrayList<WordDefinition>();

                    for (int i = 0; i < allWordDefinitions.size(); i++) {
                        if (s.equals("")) {
                        } else {
                        if (allWordDefinitions.get(i).YOUR_MODEL_METHODNAME
                                    .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(s)) {
                            searchProducts.add(allWordDefinitions.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                listUpdate(searchProducts);
            }

        }

        private void listUpdate(List<WordDefinition> searchProducts) {
          // Here you call your adapter.
        }
```

If code works for you then please mark it as acceptable.

Comment: A red marker says: searchProducts cannot be resolved to a variable. How can I solve this?

Comment: I'll mark it as acceptable if code works for me. But I have few questions: in "your_model_methodname", should I put "word"? And, what should put in "here you call your adapter"?

Comment: @HollyIkki i gave you a **working** example, what is wrong with it?

Comment: @pskink The ListView is not updated with the text that i typed in edittext (it gets a specific data from database if exists).

Comment: @HollyIkki did you run my **exact** code (with no modifications)? what was not working?

Comment: Sorry to reply late I was busy.Call your adapter means in this method you should set your list view adapter. Moreover, method name is your WordDefinition's class methods. Here you should declare your desired method name with you want to compare your entered string.